# Why am I getting a dereferencing NULL pointer and possible buffer overrun warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
struct Buffer {
    uint8_t* data;
    int size;

    Buffer(std::string input):
        data((uint8_t*)malloc(input.size() * sizeof(uint8_t))),
        size(input.size())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            data[i] = (uint8_t)input.at(i); // Warnings here
        }
    }
    ~Buffer() {
        free(data);
    }
}
```

I'm getting these two warnings from MSVC at the line `data[i] = (uint8_t)input.at(i);`

```
"C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'data'"
"C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'data': the writable size is
        'input.size()*sizeof(uint8_t)' bytes, but '2' bytes may be written"
```

Even if it isn't useful, the code works, but why am I getting these warnings?

Comment: Why aren't you verifying that the `malloc` call succeeded? And why are you using `malloc` when `calloc` looks more appropriate?

Comment: Also, **C++ is not C**. If you're actually writing C++ then you shouldn't be calling C runtime functions like `malloc` and `free` directly.

Comment: `malloc` can return `nullptr`.

Comment: @Dai I don't need the memory to be initialized to 0

Comment: I'm tempted to say the second warning is a false positive. I have no idea where it's getting 2 from and it still happens for me if `malloc` is checked properly.

Comment: That's the confusing way Visual Studio warns about `malloc`'s possible failure. There is buffer overrun only if `malloc` fails. The message will go away if you add a test `if(!data){error/throw...}`

Comment: If you really are using C++, do you know that what you are building already is available in the standard library? It is called std::vector. Usually C++ code has no malloc/free, and almost no new/delete in it (last one because you can use library functions that do new/delete internally and/or because there is std::make_unique and std::make_shared)

Comment: Keep an eye out for the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Make sure you have no cases where `input` is empty.

Comment: According to Microft docs, the first warning would be because `malloc()` can return null.   The second is a warning of an index out of bounds (i.e.  the index is potentially being used to access an element past the end of what is allocated).   From that, the first warning is because you're not checking the return value from `malloc()`, and the second is a side-effect of the first.   In any event, avoid using `malloc()` in C++ - use a `new` expression instead.   And, even better, avoid using a `new` expression - use something like `std::vector<uint8_t>` and initialise it as a copy of `input`.

Comment: By the way, VS2019 had a bug, it's fixed in VS2022. Which version do you use?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - eeek, what was the bug that was relevant here?

Comment: @Dai for users of Microsoft compiler  usage of `malloc()`  is a cargo cult. There is no difference between `std::malloc` and `malloc` in implementation (essentially Win API platform doesn't have C compiler, only a  kinda-C++ one) and traditionally MS implementation of `new operator` is a call of `malloc` and call of hook function that tracks each object creation (same goes with `delete[]`)... which makes a `malloc`/`free` for fundamental types or large arrays much faster than `new[]`/`delete[]` at least in debug mode.

Comment: `std::vector<uint8_t> data; std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(data), [](char ch) { return static_cast<uint8_t>(ch); });` -- That does what that entire `Buffer` class is doing, without all of that `malloc` stuff going on.

Comment: @davidbak It's not a compiler bug, it's just Code Analysis warnings, I think it's only in VS2019. It can be configured, see answer.

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to use a vector you can still use unique_ptr, which obviates the need for an explicit destructor and prevents accidental copies (I assume they would all be accidental).

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `malloc` succeeded.

Other than that, in Visual Studio 2019, you may still get Code Analysis messages which can be reproduced as follows:

```
std::string str{"abc"};
const auto size = str.size();
if (!str.size()) return; //if(!size) return; will remove the warning
uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
if (!buf) return;
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    buf[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(str.at(i)); //<-warning

...
warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'buf':  
the writable size is 'Temp_value_#9' bytes, but '2' bytes might be written.
```

Note that the above code checks if `data` is valid and the boundaries are checked in the `for` loop. Code Analysis doesn't seem able to keep track of `str.size()`

If we replace `if(!str.size())` with `if(!size)` the warning goes away.

These are not the main compiler warnings, it's Code Analysis trying to be extra helpful. It can be turned off or configured to a different settings in Project Properties -> Code Analysis. It doesn't do this in VS2022.

Side note, use `std::vector` etc. for memory management if this is within your own program. In rare cases when you are accessing APIs or old libraries, you maybe forced to use `malloc` or `free` (usually not both), or use `new/delete/delete[]...`, they are valid c++ functions.